# Problema con json_decode en PHP

Tags: php, json, php7

tengo un problema estoy tratando de acceder a un json que me viene por url de la siguienete manera

`{
   "items":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"INV\/2020\/0001",
         "type":"out_invoice"
      }
   ]
}`

Y estoy tratando de  coger este json de esta manera 
`

```
<?php

$response = file_get_contents("my Url que trae el json");
echo ($response); 

$response=json_decode($response,true);

var_dump($response);
```

En el primer echo sale el json pero cuando pasa por el json_decode se convierte en null , porfa si me pueden dar una luz de los que puede pasar o si estoy usando mal json_decode , o si el formato del json esta mal .

Comment: Después de hacer el json_decode, ejecuta `json_last_error_msg` este método te dirá un mensaje de texto orientativo de que ha pasado al intentar decodificar el json. Cuéntanos qué te pone, a ver si te ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Intenta asignar una nueva variable como response en vez de usar la que se procesa:

```
$res = file_get_contents("my Url que trae el json");
echo $res; //Tenias parentesis en el echo, echo no usa parentesis

$response=json_decode($res,true);

var_dump($response);
```

Comment: hola , gracias por tu ayuda pero igual con esos cambios me sigue dando null en response

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de probar tu código y parece que va bien, hice una prueba desde postman y me responde y todo, no se si podré ayudar pero te dejo lo que añadí en file_get_contents:

```
<?php 
$response = file_get_contents("php://input");
echo ($response); 

$response=json_decode($response, true);

var_dump($response);
?>
```

- `php://input` -> Es un flujo de sólo lectura que permite leer datos del cuerpo solicitado. En el caso de peticiones POST. Según la pág de PHP.